# Base64 in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, filter, base64

Is there something like

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE base64(bar) LIKE '%bararar%'
```

in SQLite?

If not, are there other compareable functions in other SQL-style databases? (MySQL, MSSQL and so on)

I really need to know this because I have a huge database where some base64-encodings of strings contain a specific character which I have to filter out. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: I don't think so, but SQLite's source is public domain so you could probably fork SQLite, write a base64 function for it and release it to the public? :) <— hint, hint

Comment: then are there other ways I can perform a query which offers my whished result?

Comment: You could try caching but this would be very slow the first time, and after each update/insertion. By the way, isn't it a bit late to program right now in Germany? :)

Comment: An alternative would be to have a separate DB which has the same data except that it's **not** base64. This database would be updated after each update on the original, so they are in sync.

Comment: I don't want to get every entry in the database to filter the needed entries manually. I am using a .NET language. That's the reason why I simply can't extend the SQLite functions... because of the .NET wrapper. We are talking about 10k+ entries btw.

Comment: @WTP, that is way more work than necessary.  SQLite supports custom functions written in C natively and many wrappers provide functionality to write custom functions in .NET, Java, ActionScript, and many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Data.SQLite supports custom functions in .NET.  If you're using a different wrapper that doesn't do this, then change the wrapper.  The latest version is here:

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

It used to be here, but is now a part of the main SQLite project:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

Example:

```
[SQLiteFunction(Name = "Base64", Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Scalar)]
class Base64SQLite : SQLiteFunction
{
  public override object Invoke(object[] args)
  {
    // assumes args[0] is a string, but you can handle binary data too
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(args[0]));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
  }
}
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of searches of this data, especially wildcard searches, then you're better off caching the data (use a trigger) and putting it into an FTS index.

Answer (score 2):

Of all the encoding and decoding algorithms, SQLite only supports hexadecimal (`hex`) out of the box.

But you can add Base64 encoding/decoding functions with the [sqlean-crypto](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/crypto.md) extension.

For example:

```sql
select load_extension('crypto.dll');

select encode('hello', 'base64');
-- aGVsbG8=

select decode('aGVsbG8=', 'base64');
-- hello
```

The extension also supports other algorithms like Base32, Base85 and URL-encode.